# Working with a non-activity class, which should be able to handle the instance variable of the calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B, and a non activity class C.

To use the methods of C, I create an instance c of C from the currently running activity (say A is in the foreground, and A has created C).

Now, I want to use the instance variables of activity A from c. What should I do?

I am trying to use the non activity C class for multiple activities. Please help me! I have researched it a lot, but still couldn't find anything useful about it. :(

This is the example code:

ActivityOne.java:

```
package com.example.vaibhav.a21matchsticks;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Example extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

// Now comes the method, I want to use in the non-activity java class.

public void buttonClick(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMe); //finds the view from the activity
    int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

    //Below code changes the view state, if the condition is true

    if(i<4) { 
        findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

Assume the xml file to have a linear layout having one EditText view (with id 'editMe') and a Button (with id 'button'). There are more than 1 activities like this, each having at least the above two views (and may be more).

My job is to create a non activity class C, to handle the conditional statement for different activities and change the respective layout accordingly.

Comment: This is extremely vague. What is class C supposed to do, exactly? If you just need to call a method on your activity class from somewhere else, you can pass an instance of it around; however, the activity lifecycle can throw some gotchas into that plan if you're not careful.

Comment: @solarshadow of course the C class in this question doesn't do anything useful. It was supposed to be an example to my question. In my original code, I have 3 activities. Each of these activities use the same code for performing a set of instructions. So I decided to put them all in one non-activity class to save some lines. But then I realized that the code, which I am going to put in this class will refer to some views of the calling activity.

Comment: Depending on the details of what you're doing, you might could build C as a superclass of your other activity classes. If you override setContentView() you can grab the views you need after calling super's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Even though a but vague, your Class C seems to be a helper class. Now, since you want to access instance variables (and possibly other information) in your C class, you need to pass them manually. Depending on what you are passing, it can be provided to Class C either in its constructor or via instance methods of the Class C itself.

For eg: based on the last statement of your question you can pass a `ViewGroup` reference from your activity to Class C via something like this:

```
public void initLayout(ViewGroup parent) {

    // Hide/unhide/perform actions/etc based on current activity needs

}
```

Similarly, you can also pass an `enum` value to Class C to differentiate between your activities in Class C. For a Class C to activity communication, you can look at `interface` in Java. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer may work for some people, but for me it will be too laborious to pass each of the views manually from all 3 of my activities. Thanks!

Comment: @vaibhavS Hmm...maybe, thats the only way to access variables from other classes. But, since you mentioned multiple views, you can pass them via instance methods or constructor of Class C as an array of views. Just sauing.